# Implement Hybrid Naive Bayes on one dataset of Bernoulli NB for categorical features and Gaussian NB for numerical features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I have a dataset of 2 numerical descriptive features and 3 categorical descriptive features. I have encoded the categorical features and scaling the nuemrical features. Now I want to use a Hybrid Naive Bayes classifier contains Bernoulli NB for categorical features and Gaussian NB for numerical features. I have tried to use Ensemble method of StackingClassifier in sklearn moduel, however, it does not have parameters that can clarify which Naive Bayes method for which part of the dataset. Is there any method that I am able to combine the two methods together and then fit the data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create 2 groups of features.

use classifier 1:  X[feature_group_1] -> Y[labels] as one classifier and classifier 2:  X[feature_group_2] -> Y[labels] as other classifier.

For prediction also, you will have to divide test features in two groups:
Xtest[feature_group_1] -> ytest1
Xtest[feature_group_2] -> ytest2

Then stack their outputs to get your final answer. For stacking you can use the VotingClassifier method.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

eclf2 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[
    ...         ('bnb', clf1), ('gnb', clf2)],
    ...         voting='soft')
```

Comment: I think the real question is that `HOW do you MERGE` the two classifiers to make a single classifier?

Comment: Voting will take the average for `soft`. Is this a good method Hybrid?

Comment: If 2 classifiers are calibrated well, 'soft' will work. But if each of them works well only in certain mutually exclusive cases then I believe we can go for 'hard" voting. It depends on how they perform individually.

Comment: Can't we just multiply the probabilities or add log probabilities to have a final probability?

Comment: Multiplying probabilities might not work . For example, one classifier is pretty confident (proba 0.9) and other not much (proba 0.1), Multiplication will yield 0.09. Instead max(prob1, prob2) or even simple average is not a bad option. If we find 1 classifier is better in general than the other, we can play with weights say 0.7clf1 + 0.3clf2.

Comment: But that is the whole point. Probabilities will be defined for both the classes. Isn't that the right way of probabilistic distribution or simply put Naive Bayes algo?

Comment: And how are you even supposed to train the Voting Classifier?? When the data is not even the same? There are two different sets of data. One classifier is supposed to be trained on the numerical and one on categorical. Voting takes just one X and Y value.